# recursively go through submodules and get changelog

Tags: git

I use

```
git ls-tree ed2d14dc10cb9fd6b92a076cd52a8769b05c19cc submodule-name | grep -E -o  "[0-9a-f]{40}"
```

to get the commit of the submodule where the main project commit was `ed2d14dc10cb9fd6b92a076cd52a8769b05c19cc?` Meaning, if the main project commit was `ed2d14dc10cb9fd6b92a076cd52a8769b05c19cc`, this gets the latest commit hash of the submodule at that commit.

How do I use this command to recursively retrieve all of the commit hashes for each submodule and do a git log with the most recent hash for each submodule to get a changelog between the two hashes?

For example, if the main project had a commit hash of A, then I want to get the latest commit hash of submodule submodule1 at A:

```
hash1 = git ls-tree A submodule1 | grep -E -o  "[0-9a-f]{40}"
```

and if the main project has latest commit hash of B, then I want to get the latest commit hash of submodule submodule1 at B.

```
hash2 = git ls-tree B submodule1 | grep -E -o  "[0-9a-f]{40}"
```

Then I want to get the git log of the two hashes for each submodule..

```
git log -- submodule1 --oneline hash1..hash2
```

How do I do this recursively for all of the submodules?

Comment: You want to be able to compare the logs for all your submodules at two different checkouts?

Comment: I want to compare the logs for the submodules given only two commit hashes from the main project.

Answer (score 0):

```
git submodule foreach --recursive '
    REV1=HEAD; 
    REV2=HEAD~10; 
    SHA1=$(cd $toplevel && git ls-tree $REV1 $path | grep -E -o  "[0-9a-f]{40}");
    SHA2=$(cd $toplevel && git ls-tree $REV2 $path | grep -E -o  "[0-9a-f]{40}"); 
    git log --oneline $SHA1...$SHA2'
```

[Here's](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) the help page for `git-submodule`.

While I think this is cool and everything, it might help to clarify your intent. :)